# A word to add other cases

Tags: word-request

Suppose I want to count applications of something

> The applications of X include Y for ...., Z for .... **Moreover**, X can be used for W.

I feel "Moreover", "Furthermore", "In addition",... are used to add another points to the points or reasons already said... but maybe not for adding another case or example? If I am right, which adverbs are used for this purpose?

Comment: Are you asking whether "moreover" is correct in the example? It is correct, though people would more often write/say "Moreover, X can *also* be used..."

Comment: @PhilEsra "Moreover" seems to me like I want to add a point not a case

Comment: *Also* is versatile.

Comment: @TRomano, true, and if using "also," you could just drop the "moreover," which is a very formal-sounding word. Ahmad, the way I read your sentence, it could be filled in with these examples--The applications of putty include smearing a thin layer for repairs, ... and globbing a thick layer as a filler. Moreover, putty can also be used for children's play if it is composed of a non-toxic substance. Is that right?

Comment: "Moreover" is just fine there with "also," but TRomano is right about "also" being a good sub--"Also, X can be..." and "X can also be..."

Another option would be "In addition, X can be..."